# Vb.net: Array.clear Clean related Array issue

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have trouble with Array.clear function

This is the simple code:

```
Dim Array1() As Double = {1, 2}
Dim Array2(UBound(Array1)) As Double
Array2 = Array1
Array.Clear(Array1, 0, Array1.Length)
```

After do the Array.Clear, it is not only Array 1 is Cleaned but also Array 2 is cleaned.

What happened here? What can i do to prevent this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What's happening:**

```
Array2 = Array1
```

The above statement doesn't copy the elements of Array1 into Array2, instead the above statement only copies the pointer as mentioned in the link below

[Assigning one array to another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkwd0xy9.aspx)

Because of the above, when you do

```
Array.Clear(Array1, 0, Array1.Length)
```

The values of Array1 are changed to 0 and Array2 points to the new values of Array 1 i.e., all 0s.

**How to prevent it:**

Use Array copy which copies the elements.

```
Dim Array1() As Double = {1, 2}
Dim Array2(UBound(Array1)) As Double
Array.Copy(Array1,Array2,Array2.Length) //Array.Copy(source, target, target.Length)
Array.Clear(Array1, 0, Array1.Length)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! this's all need

Comment: @NguyenDucLinh Most welcome! Glad I could help :)